# PDO driver is not enabled after installation

Tags: pdo, centos7

[image]

I have installed `rh-php70-pdo.x86_64` package and restart the httpd.service.
But PDO driver is not shown as enabled in phpinfo().

I also try with `php-pdo.x86_64` but failed.

I use CentOS 7.

Comment: Please give us the output from `rpm -q php`

Comment: @user3788685 `$ rpm -q php
package php is not installed`

Comment: What version of php do you have installed ? and from where?

Comment: @user3788685 https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/php7

Comment: Whats does you `phpinfo` say when you check that ?

Comment: if your not sure how see this link; http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php